# Проблема с define в PHP

Tags: php

Есть файлы *'inc/1.php'*, *'inc/2.php'* и *'3.php'* (названия файлов взяты за примеры).

Файл *'inc/1.php'* содержит объявление константы:

```
define ('I_S', 'http://test/images/');
```

Она может быть нормально использована в самом *1.php*.

В файле *'inc/2.php'*:

```
require_once('inc/1.php');
```

и в нём константа также доступна.

В файле *3.php*:

```
require_once 'inc/2php';
```

но там эта константа уже недоступна: *Use of undefined constant*.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Соберите минимальный код, к котором видно проблему. Сейчас с трудом соображаю, что вы навертели там)

Comment: Поправил кое-как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего нужно заменить

```
 require_once 'inc/2.php';
```

на

```
include('inc/2.php');
```

Comment: А что не так с синтаксисом?
В одном каталоге находятся _3.php_ и папка _inc_.
Нет, проблема не с путями, т.к. я использовал другой файл из того же каталога, где и _1.php_, вставив объявление туда - всё работало.

Comment: Да, такая замена помогла, спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Надеюсь понятно почему именно include?

Comment: Ну да. Require просто вставляет код на место функции, и выходит проблема с путями, т.к. require, расчитанный на 2.php, используется в 3.php
А include сначала исполняет код во включаемом файле, и тот require происходит в 2.php, на который и расчитан этот путь.
Теперь я решу эту проблему собственно изменением способа указания пути (буду ставить абсолютные).

Comment: Кстати, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] использовать (везде перед началом пути, мне так удобнее) - нормально? Ну или в файле, который всегда и везде подключается, прописать:

    $root = 'root/path";